# Ending program properly

Tags: java

I have a game, ConnectFour that plays and what not. But when the user is finished with a game, there is a prompt that says "would you like to play again? If the user types yes, then it works. But if the user types no, it prints, "Thanks for playing." But the output in the terminal window is:

> Congrats Red won the game.
>
> Would you like to play again? Y/N
>
> n
>
> Thanks for playing.

It does not reload the line that you can use to input stuff back into the terminal. This line

```
Jacks-MacBook-Pro:Cs124 Jack_XXX$
```

I don't know if that's a function of the main program using a GUI and how it wont close. But I have to hit control C every time to end the program this way and I want to know if there is a way to stop that.

The code for main is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

ConnectFour connectFour= new ConnectFour();
BoardView view =  connectFour.getView();

JFrame worldFrame = new JFrame();
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();


view.repaint();

worldFrame.setContentPane(view);
worldFrame.add(buttonPanel);
worldFrame.validate();
worldFrame.pack();
worldFrame.setVisible(true);


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to Connect Four. The object of the game is to get four of the same colored pieces in a row.");
System.out.println("Red will go first.");

//sets up the gameboard and then draws it
for (int i = 0; i < connectFour.getGameBoard().length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < connectFour.getGameBoard()[0].length; j++) {
    connectFour.getGameBoard()[i][j] = 0;
  }
}

view.repaint();

connectFour.printGameBoard();

String pwon = "";
boolean playgame=true;
//actual gamecode
while(playgame=true){
    boolean game=false;
    while (game == false) {

        System.out.println("Red, which column would you like to move into?");
        System.out.println("Note Column Numbers 1 to 7 are accepted.");

        int x = input.nextInt();
        connectFour.move1(x, connectFour.getGameBoard());
        if ((connectFour.getGameBoard()[0][x-1]==1)||(connectFour.getGameBoard()[0][x-1]==2)){
            System.out.println("Invalid move. You lost your turn");
        }
        view.repaint();
        connectFour.printGameBoard();

        if (connectFour.isFourInaRow()) {
            pwon = "Red";
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Black, which column would you like to move into?");
        System.out.println("Note Column Numbers 1 to 7 are accepted.");

        x = input.nextInt();
        connectFour.move2(x, connectFour.getGameBoard());
        if ((connectFour.getGameBoard()[0][x-1]==1)||(connectFour.getGameBoard()[0][x-1]==2)){
            System.out.println("Invalid move. You lost your turn");
        }
        view.repaint();
        connectFour.printGameBoard();

        if (connectFour.isFourInaRow()) {
            pwon = "Black";
            break;
        }

        }

    if (connectFour.checkRow() == true) {
        System.out.println("row");
    } else if (connectFour.checkColumn() == true) {
        System.out.println("col");
    } else if (connectFour.checkDiag() == true) {
        System.out.println("diag");
    } else{ 
        System.out.println("draw");

    }

    System.out.println("Congrats " + pwon + " won the game.");
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y/N");
    input.nextLine();
    String answer = input.nextLine();

    if((answer.equals("N"))||(answer.equals("n"))){
        break;
    }
 }
 System.out.println("Thanks for playing.");


 }
```

Comment: So you want to exit the game after the `System.out.println("Thanks for playing.");` line? Try `System.exit(0);` If I misunderstood however, let me know and I'll take a look again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a JFrame, the program starts a new thread running the message loop. It won't terminate while this loop is running.

Simplest thing is to just call `System.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Two input.nextLine()?

```
input.nextLine();
String answer = input.nextLine();
```

you write only

```
String answer = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: it doesn't load for some reason that way. trust me.

Comment: you can change break; in System.exit(0);

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
if ( answer . toUpperCase ( ) . equals ( "N" ) ) 
{
    System . out . println ( "Thanks for playing!" ) ; 
    System . exit ( 0 ) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `System.exit();` to exit the application. Also, you should set a default close operation on your `Jframe`. Something like `worldFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`